# How to add software RAID-1 to an existing system?

Tags: linux, raid, mdadm, ubuntu-14.04

I couldn't find any tutorials for converting a non-RAID Linux system (Ubuntu 14.04 in my case) into a **disk-level** RAID-1 system after installing a second disk (`/dev/sdb`)

Is the following correct?

```
sgdisk --replicate=/dev/sdb /dev/sda # copy partition table
sgdisk -G /dev/sdb # randomize IDs
mdadm --create /dev/md --level=mirror --raid-devices=2 /dev/sda missing
mdadm /dev/md -a /dev/sdb
echo "DEVICE /dev/sda /dev/sdb" >> /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf # is this needed?
mdadm --detail --scan >> /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf  
dpkg-reconfigure mdadm
```

Do I need to do anything about `grub`, or will it be copied together with the rest of `/dev/sda`?

(**Extra**: I found a tutorial here: http://feeding.cloud.geek.nz/posts/setting-up-raid-on-existing/, but it advocates copying data manually from a live partition, which seems wrong (data race), and also it applies `mdadm` at the partition level, while I want to mirror the whole disk)

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Comment: Mouse over the down arrow; the popup says "*This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful*". Downvotes without comment may be presumed to be for at least one of those reasons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would very highly not recommend doing what you're suggesting - you'll have a very non-standard configuration that puts you in "if you've gotten this far you should know what you are going" territory, decreasing the chances of support for this down the track.

The approach that will get you a sane configuration will be:

1. take backups
2. reinstall system
3. restore from backup

You *can* run RAID in whole-of-disk mode, but you'll have to make sure that any replacement disks are exactly the same size (or bigger); plus you'll have to make sure that your BIOS doesn't try to interpret the start of the disk as a partition table. See [this superuser question](https://superuser.com/questions/394988/can-i-use-an-entire-drive-for-as-a-software-raid-member) for some of the pitfalls.

Comment: Are you against disk-level software raid or against adding RAID to an existing system?

Comment: @MaxB I would advice against configuring the entire disk as RAID. A much more reasonable approach is to configure RAID on a per partition basis. Moving an existing system to RAID without reinstalling is definitely possible, but you'll have to know what you are doing. It involves first creating a RAID on new partitions, and then copying the existing file system onto the RAID. After that the old partition can be deleted to make room for another RAID.

Comment: @MaxB let's say you pull a disk, put it on a shelf, and someone else picks it up and plugs it into another machine. No partition table (i.e. whole disk RAID)? Their OS may decide that it's "unformatted" and offer to format it for them. Then again, unknown partition type might equal "unformatted" too, depending on how clever the OS is. Label your disks if they're ever not in a machine! Label the disk caddies if they *are* in a machine.